# How to format Dates on Category Axis in amCharts Line Chart?

Tags: amcharts

**amCharts Line Chart**

When amCharts line chart is zoomed around end of the year, it hides the letter Jan and places the number for Year. [Please refer JSFiddle in the comment below]

Requirement is to have Date format similar to: Nov 2014, Dec 2014, Jan 2015, Feb 2015.

In other words:

How to format Dates on Category Axis similar to below?

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: JSFiddle for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/onzdxobe/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these two lines in the properties of the categoryAxis.

```
"boldPeriodBeginning":false,
"markPeriodChange":false,
```

This should get you the desired solution.

Comment: you can further format the dates as per your need using dateFormat property.

Answer (score 1):

As i'm not allowed to comment other posts yet, i'm posting the JSFiddle i made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/76rxbjzw/).
**Note** that the answer of Anurag is the correct answer already, so the credits belong to him.
I used the `dateFormat` (as anurag mentioned in his comment) to format the displayed date on the `categoryAxis`. (see [docs](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats))
Further i didn't used the `"boldPeriodBeginning"` because it's already set false by `"markPeriodChange"`.

Comment: Thnaks Gerric for spinning the fiddle!